# Cannot grant server roles to self using local DB SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am not the admin on my work machine. I had SQL Server 2012 installed and I cannot create or import a DB. Under security I tried granting my windows UN 'dbcreator' and do not have permission. I log into my local server using my machine name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're going to have to get the person who installed SQL Server to make you an admin.

In the past, SQL Server used to make all windows administrators SQL Server admins.  This changed around SQL 2008.  The person who installed SQL Server *is* an admin by default, however.

[There are ways to grant yourself access to SQL Server if you've locked yourself out](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2465/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-if-you-are-completely-locked-out/), but they require administrative privileges (to stop and start services).